# How to use different resource sets for different productFlavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Im trying to use a series of different resource folders for my product flavors but at the moment what Im doing isnt working for all flavors which is weird.

Can some one just point me to where I can simply see how to assign an entire resource directory to a productFlavor. Like I said It works for two flavors (the main one and another) and then the rest all default to the main set.

Comment: Mind posting what you have done so far?

Comment: Did you try this [link](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants), this has a good sample but the example shown there is for 2 flavors, but extending for multiple flavors should not be that difficult.

Comment: The same logic works for x number of flavors -- I have a project with 10 flavors and don't see any difference in behavior compared to 2 flavors. We need a more detailed description of what you are trying to accomplish and what's wrong to know how to help.

Comment: Please provide your `build.gradle` of project to see what is going there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix I came up with for this issue was to explicitly declare my res files for my flavors that werent working by using sourceSets like this

```
sourceSets{
    flavor6{
        res.srcDirs = ['src/flavor6/res']
    }
}
```